# Pandas, Remove consecutive duplicates grouped by unique identifier

Tags: python, pandas

Current dataframe is as follows:

```
df = pd.read_csv('filename.csv', delimiter=',')

print(df)
idx   uniqueID      String 

0        1           'hello'
1        1           'goodbye'
2        1           'goodbye'
3        1           'happy'
4        2           'hello'
5        2           'hello'
6        2           'goodbye'
7        3           'goodbye' 
8        3           'hello'
9        3           'hello'
10       4           'hello'
11       5           'goodbye'
```

Expected Output:

```
idx   uniqueID      String 

0        1           'hello'
1        1           'goodbye'
3        1           'happy'
4        2           'hello'
6        2           'goodbye'
7        3           'goodbye' 
8        3           'hello'
10       4           'hello'
11       5           'goodbye'
```

Question: **How do I remove the consecutive duplicates only of the same uniqueID?**

What I've tried to do thus far:

`df = df[(df['String '].shift() != df['String ']) | (df['uniqueID'] != df['uniqueID'])]`

I'm not sure what case I need to include to ensure it looks specifically at the uniqueID. Any and all suggestions are appreciated. Thanks

Comment: last value for idx=11 should be 'goodbye'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forget to shift the `uniqueID` column to ensure same uniqueID. But shifting only works if `uniqueID` is consecutive, you can sort by `uniqueID` column first to ensure it is `consecutive`.

```py
out = (df.sort_values('uniqueID')
       [lambda df: (df['String'].shift() != df['String']) | (df['uniqueID'].shift() != df['uniqueID'])]
       #.sort_index() # since sort values changes index order, you can optionally convert back to original with sort_index
      )
```

```
print(out)

    idx  uniqueID     String
0     0         1    'hello'
1     1         1  'goodbye'
3     3         1    'happy'
4     4         2    'hello'
6     6         2  'goodbye'
7     7         3  'goodbye'
8     8         3    'hello'
10   10         4    'hello'
11   11         5  'goodbye'
```

Comment: Luckily, all uniqueIDs are already grouped together with the data I'm working with. But good to know in case that ever changes. Your solution appears to work! Thank you my friend. Is there documentation somewhere on pandas that describes how exactly this shifting works w/ specific params?

Comment: @Ev0 I think you can check https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html

Answer (score 1):

use [shift](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html?highlight=shift#pandas.DataFrame.shift) and compare the uniqueid and string between current and previous.

```
df= df[~( 
    (df['uniqueID']==df['uniqueID'].shift(1)) & 
    (df['String'].eq(df['String'].shift(1)))
)]
```

```
    idx     uniqueID    String
0   0   1   'hello'
1   1   1   'goodbye'
3   3   1   'happy'
4   4   2   'hello'
6   6   2   'goodbye'
7   7   3   'goodbye'
8   8   3   'hello'
10  10  4   'hello'
11  11  5   'goodbye'
```

Comment: This is close, but it does not seem to follow the requirement to only drop consecutive duplicates. For example, if I had 4 values in unique ID 1. And they were 'hello' 'hello' 'goodbye' 'hello', I would only want the second 'hello' to be dropped.

Comment: Yes it does! Thank you What do I do if I've got two different working solutions to my question? New to stack overflow..